# Cleaning up post that has been cited by OEIS

Tags: discussion

An editor at OEIS placed a link to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867135/28555) into each OEIS entry linked-to by the question. What clean-up is suggested to make the post stand the test of time? Maybe removal of the *Mathematica* code from the OP, since it is now available at OEIS? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I am slightly confused. You are the OP of the question, but then why write in the third person? (Also, it seems that you are the editor of OEIS, no?)

Comment: @user1729, I inserted the _Mathematica_ code and the formula into the two OEIS sequences (_subject to approval by the editors.)_ The link was inserted by someone else.

Comment: @user1729, _third person_ is a stylistic method used in math papers.

Comment: The third person is not commonly used in maths. Rather, the first person ("we") tends to be used. See, for example, [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/20073) academia.SE answer, or [this](http://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/MathWriting.pdf) helpful pdf. (I use the third person in occasional exceptional circumstances though: "The author would like to thank...", or "In a forthcoming paper of the author...", etc.) With this kind of question though it is better to use the first person, as it stops confusion and helps everyone to see the bigger picture.

Comment: “The third person is not commonly used in maths”: I can't say for sure for each English speaking country, but in France, and French is my native tong, I can say it is common.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To help Math.SE stand the test of time, we assume *all* external links may break.  As such, we should assume that OEIS may go down and Math.SE survives it.  In this event, we would *lose* information if we delete the Mathematica code.  Thus, we certainly don't want to remove that.

I think the post looks fine in its current state and that clean up is not necessary.

If I were to change *anything*, I would copy the definitions of `A038110` and `A038111` into the question (so people don't have to leave MSE to know what they are), but I don't think that's very important.